# how brittle is chromium?

Tags: material-science

I'm doing a small design project, and considering chromium as the material of choice (the element Im making requires high Young's modulus).

however, I've read on many sites including this one, that it is extremely brittle, but I did not find out how much.

it would mean a lot to me if someone can help me visualize it.

is it brittle as glass, or as dry clay? or is it just relatively brittle compared to steel?

is there a form of measurement that could help me out in comparing it to other materials. thank you

Comment: Pure chromium is very malleable.

Comment: Would [engineering.se] be a better home for this question? (If so, don't cross-post - flag for a moderator to migrate).

Answer (score 1):

in commercial form, it is much more brittle than steel but not as brittle as clay or glass. this can be easily demonstrated by striking a chrome-plated thin steel part with a hammer, or by dumping a motorcycle with chrome-plated mufflers so they strike the pavement at speed. the steel beneath the chrome bends readily but the chrome exfoliates into thin, sharp-edged flakes and shards.

brittleness is measured by means of the charpy impact test, as defined by the ASTM. this test is a measure of the amount of energy required to fracture a piece of material. very brittle materials require little energy to break; ductile materials absorb much larger amounts of energy before fracture.